ImportError: cannot import name 'ArcFace' from 'arcface'
arcface
from arcface import ArcFace
face_rec = ArcFace.ArcFace()
emb1 = face_rec.calc_emb("~/Downloads/test.jpg")
print(emb1)
emb2 = face_rec.calc_emb("~/Downloads/test2.jpg")
face_rec.get_distance_embeddings(emb1, emb2)


I have installed arcface and the code above is from arcface's official documentation.
I printed the contents of arcface library
['builtins', 'cached', 'doc', 'file', 'loader', 'name', 'package', 'spec']

complete traceback please

Check if you installed arcface under the same user as Python; check Python-related paths at Path value at Enviroment...

@Bohdan I have installed in the right environment. I don't know if its a problem with the library itself.

The issue was solved after I updated my pip version.
